# Autoincrement version number in Jenkins + Maven

Tags: maven, jenkins

I want to have autoincrementing version number in Maven during each build.

I tried using `autoincrement-versions-maven-plugin`, it works fine. But, the modified POM file need to be committed back to SVN from inside Jenkins.

How do I do that?

I have seen this thread: [Incrementing Maven Project Version with Jenkins/Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807226/incrementing-maven-project-version-with-jenkins-git)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SVN Publisher](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SVN+Publisher)

If I understand your problem, you  need to make commit on jenkins(commit changes on .pom file)?

Enjoy!

Comment: I tried it, given a sample file, the file is not getting updated in SVN.

Comment: I think you can write execute script for commit your changes, add this scripts to post-build actions on jenkins. if your jenkins-server on linux use - bash, or windows - use batch.

Comment: If I am going to write scripts, then why do I need SVN Publisher?

Comment: if you write script, you unneed plugins

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [Maven scm plugin](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/usage.html) for this.  Just setup an scm block in your pom, e.g.

```
<project>
...
    <scm>
        <url>http://somerepository.com/view.cvs</url>
        <connection>scm:svn:http://somerepository.com/svn_repo/trunk</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://somerepository.com/svn_repo/trunk</developerConnection>
    </scm>
...
</project>
```

And then add a Jenkins Maven build step with goal 'scm:checkin' and parameters like commit message, repository username, and repository password.  More info [here](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/checkin-mojo.html).